# setTimeout me devuelve una hora de diferencia en celular, la fecha la estoy agarrando desde el servidor. en PC si me da la hora exacta

Tags: javascript, jquery

Este es el codigo que utilizo para una cuenta regresiva de una subasta, todo esta bien y funciona pero el problema es que en celular me lo da con una hora de diferencia, aún agarrando la fecha del servidor.

y en PC me da correcta la información, es decir la hora en que finaliza el conteo es la misma que tengo grabada en la base de datos.

Solo ese detalle que en el celular no me arroja bien la fecha, alguien le ha pasado algo similar?

Necesito ayuda a ver quien me puede orientar ya que no le he encontrado por ningun lado.

```
;(function($){  

    $.fn.cuentaAtras = function() {
        return this.each (function(indice) {    
    
            var fecha = new Date ($(this).text()),
            contenedor = '#'+$(this).attr('id'),
            mensaje = $(this).attr('title');
            $.fn.cuentaAtras.refresca(Math.floor(new Date(fecha-new Date(<? echo $data; ?>)).valueOf()/1000), contenedor, mensaje);
                        

        });
    };

    $.fn.cuentaAtras.refresca = function(secs, id, mensaje) {

        function calcage(secs, num1, num2) {
            s = ((Math.floor(secs/num1))%num2).toString();
            if (s.length < 2)
                s = "0" + s;
            return s;
        };
        
        if (secs < 0) {
            $(id).html(mensaje);
            $(id).addClass('reloj_success');    
            $(id).removeClass('reloj_hot');
        } 
        else {
            
        if (secs < 3600) {
            $(id).addClass('reloj_hot');    
            $(id).removeClass('reloj_yellow');  
        } else if (secs < 18000) {
            $(id).addClass('reloj_yellow'); 
        }

            var dia = calcage(secs,86400,100000),
            hora = calcage(secs,3600,24),
            min = calcage(secs,60,60),
            seg = calcage(secs,1,60);

            if(dia == 00 ) {
                        $(id).html ("<strong>"+hora+":"+min+":"+seg+"</strong>");
            } else {
            $(id).html ("<strong>"+dia+"</strong> Days <strong>"+hora+":"+min+":"+seg+"</strong>");
            }
            setTimeout("$.fn.cuentaAtras.refresca(" + (secs-1) + ", '" + id + "', '"+ mensaje +"')", 1000);
        };

        return this;
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: como estas seguro de que la estas obteniendo del servidor???

Comment: el comparativo es una fecha de la base de datos por medio de una variable y la compara con la que yo le doy <? echo $data; ?>

<? $data = time()*1000; ?>  

En mi PC y en algunos celulares esta todo bien pero en otros no, solo celulares...

Comment: y como sabes que en esos equipos $data tiene un dato correcto; como tu problema es muy situacional no tenemos manera de comprobar el error... es un error de configuracion del servidor o del cliente pero no vemos error o problema en tu codigo de momento... necesitamos que coloques en el post las pruebas que has realizado a nivel de codigo y de imagenes de los resultado si es posible... de lo contrario no podemos darte mas ayuda; ya que el otro problema es que logres hacer un debug de la informacion con un nivel de seguridad adecuado.